# SolutionDir no T4 Template

Tags: t4, scaffold

Estou tentando carregar um *assembly* no *template* T4, porém ao tentar usar o `$(SolutionDir)` o meu *assembly* não carrega, só funciona se eu colocar o caminho completo.

Assim funciona

```
<#@ assembly name="d:\Projetos\Meus.Scaffold\bin\Debug\Meus.Scaffold.dll" #>
```

Assim não funciona

```
<#@ assembly name="$(SolutionDir)\bin\Debug\Meus.Scaffold.dll" #>
```

Sem que das duas formas o VS não acusa que não foi possível carregar o *assembly*, porém ao rodar o comando

```
Scaffold Triggers Teste Teste -force
```

Tenho o erro

```
Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate : d:\Projetos\Projeto.Web\CodeTemplates\Scaffolders\Trigger\ConexaoTriggerDelete.cs.t4(3,11) : error CS0246: Compiling 
transformation: The type or namespace name 'Meus' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
At d:\Projetos\Projeto.Web\CodeTemplates\Scaffolders\Trigger\Trigger.ps1:15 char:1
+ Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $outputPath -Template $Template `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : T4Scaffolding.Cmdlets.AddProjectItemViaTemplateCmdlet
```